# COPY INTO command is not working in command line terminal

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I want to incrementally load data into a delta table. However, my "COPY INTO" command is not working in spark sql prompt of command line terminal.

[image]

The same command is working in databricks.

[image]

Please let me know does this command only works in databricks environment.

Comment: Yes, but I want to understand why it is not in command line tool on on-prem system ?

Answer (score 1):

The `COPY INTO` is a SQL statement specific to Databricks ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html)), you can't use it with the open source Spark.  But basically it's just a simplification of the following streaming code:

```py
df = spark.readStream.format("parquet").load(input_path)
df = df.select(....) # optionally transform the input data
df.writeStream.format("delta")\ 
  .trigger(availableNow=True) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "some location") \
  .start(output_path)
```

Comment: Is your code going to incrementally load into the target path.? Because I can see you are reading and simply writing it. In which type of mode is it going write e.g. overwrite, append etc

Comment: Yes, it will be incremental (you need to provide a checkpoint location). The default output mode is `append`, so it could be omitted..

Comment: Hi Alex, I am not using streaming data. This is just a delta table and I want to load data into it. Checkpoint can only be used in streaming data. I want to repeat my same question. Will the below query still work : -
df = spark.read.format("json").load("<file_path>")
df.write.format("delta").save("<target_path>")
Do you still agree with it ?

Comment: COPY INTO is using streaming under the hood to provide incremental ingestion.